# Set operation with condition

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

My object looks like:

```
{
   _id: ObjectId(),
   unpaid: 500,
   paid: false
}
```

and the statement:

```
db.items.update({
    unpaid: {
        $gte: 500
    }
}, {
    $inc: {
        unpaid: -500
    }
});
```

When unpaid will be equal zero, the paid field needs also to change to true.

Is it possible to do this with one query?

Comment: No, that's two queries. Two different conditions resulting in updates on two different fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, `MongoDB` queries are not flexible enough to trigger an post query event. You could do it in two ways, but both involve firing more than a single query:

The first approach, involves:

- Finding and Updating all the records with `unpaid >= 500` in a single
  update statement.
- Followed by another update statement which updates the `paid` field
  to true for all `unpaid = 0`.

Code:

```
db.items.update({
    "unpaid": {
        $gte: 500
    }
}, {
    $inc: {
        "unpaid": -500
    }
});

db.items.update({
    "unpaid":0,"paid":false
}, {
    $set: {
        "paid": true
    }
});
```

This approach may not be suitable if atomic updates matter in your application, and could lead to adding extra app logic to see things correctly before the `paid` field has been updated.

The second approach, involves:

- Finding all the records with `unpaid >= 500`.
- Performing a [bulk](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk.find.update/#Bulk.find.update) update. Each update will set both the `unpaid` and
  the `paid` fields at the same time.

Code:

```
var bulk = db.items.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
db.items.find({"unpaid":{$gte:500}}).forEach(function(doc){
 var unpaid = doc.unpaid-500;
 var update = {$set:{"unpaid":unpaid}};
 if(unpaid <= 0){
  update.$set["paid"] = true;
 }
  bulk.find({"_id":doc._id }).update(update);
})
bulk.execute();
```